# So I made a music bot, but i don't know if this is a discord error

Tags: http, discord.py

I wanted to make a livestream play in a vc! IT WORKED but now I get the following "error"

```
[https @ 0xe5b5c0] Cannot reuse HTTP connection for different host: r2---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com:-1 != r4---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com:-1
[hls,applehttp @ 0xc06250] keepalive request failed for 'https://r4---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/id/DWcJFNfaw9c.2/itag/96/source/yt_live_broadcast/expire/1603923091/ei/M5iZX4_VIMLUW57fiOAO/ip/2a01:cb00:39c:2900:835b:2f40:d2bf:7a5d/requiressl/yes/ratebypass/yes/live/1/goi/160/sgoap/gir%3Dyes%3Bitag%3D140/sgovp/gir%3Dyes%3Bitag%3D137/hls_chunk_host/r4---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com/playlist_duration/30/manifest_duration/30/vprv/1/playlist_type/DVR/initcwndbps/6610/mh/Ms/mm/44/mn/sn-25ge7nsl/ms/lva/mv/m/mvi/4/pl/30/keepalive/yes/mt/1603901358/disable_polymer/true/sparams/expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,ratebypass,live,goi,sgoap,sgovp,playlist_duration,manifest_duration,vprv,playlist_type/sig/AOq0QJ8wRAIgUQGg9L0Aj_FXl9CqYP0o8t-Dn23Jh0y93xgYGouOHZMCIExicbcOpmWTdWCrUExX8dHFMcPEDXtkXXRplyCl49Y1/lsparams/hls_chunk_host,initcwndbps,mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl/lsig/AG3C_xAwRQIhAKVCR3lS5k-ryagc8fHuvIzMuMDccwvOXmxj8fT7PjUyAiB8D1MwZ0tmEoJidXuttZSKuxCDlc-J5gV43lRScjepXQ%3D%3D/playlist/index.m3u8/sq/3831774/goap/clen%3D81133%3Blmt%3D1603879520260124/govp/clen%3D258451%3Blmt%3D1603879520260122/dur/5.000/file/seg.ts', retrying with new connection: Invalid argument
[https @ 0xf64dd0] Cannot reuse HTTP connection for different host: r2---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com:-1 != r4---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com:-1
[hls,applehttp @ 0xc06250] keepalive request failed for 'https://r4---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/id/DWcJFNfaw9c.2/itag/96/source/yt_live_broadcast/expire/1603923091/ei/M5iZX4_VIMLUW57fiOAO/ip/2a01:cb00:39c:2900:835b:2f40:d2bf:7a5d/requiressl/yes/ratebypass/yes/live/1/goi/160/sgoap/gir%3Dyes%3Bitag%3D140/sgovp/gir%3Dyes%3Bitag%3D137/hls_chunk_host/r4---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com/playlist_duration/30/manifest_duration/30/vprv/1/playlist_type/DVR/initcwndbps/6610/mh/Ms/mm/44/mn/sn-25ge7nsl/ms/lva/mv/m/mvi/4/pl/30/keepalive/yes/mt/1603901358/disable_polymer/true/sparams/expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,ratebypass,live,goi,sgoap,sgovp,playlist_duration,manifest_duration,vprv,playlist_type/sig/AOq0QJ8wRAIgUQGg9L0Aj_FXl9CqYP0o8t-Dn23Jh0y93xgYGouOHZMCIExicbcOpmWTdWCrUExX8dHFMcPEDXtkXXRplyCl49Y1/lsparams/hls_chunk_host,initcwndbps,mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl/lsig/AG3C_xAwRQIhAKVCR3lS5k-ryagc8fHuvIzMuMDccwvOXmxj8fT7PjUyAiB8D1MwZ0tmEoJidXuttZSKuxCDlc-J5gV43lRScjepXQ%3D%3D/playlist/index.m3u8/sq/3831775/goap/clen%3D81296%3Blmt%3D1603879520260134/govp/clen%3D224812%3Blmt%3D1603879520260132/dur/5.000/file/seg.ts', retrying with new connection: Invalid argument
[https @ 0xe48430] Cannot reuse HTTP connection for different host: r2---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com:-1 != r4---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com:-1
[hls,applehttp @ 0xc06250] keepalive request failed for 'https://r4---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/id/DWcJFNfaw9c.2/itag/96/source/yt_live_broadcast/expire/1603923091/ei/M5iZX4_VIMLUW57fiOAO/ip/2a01:cb00:39c:2900:835b:2f40:d2bf:7a5d/requiressl/yes/ratebypass/yes/live/1/goi/160/sgoap/gir%3Dyes%3Bitag%3D140/sgovp/gir%3Dyes%3Bitag%3D137/hls_chunk_host/r4---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com/playlist_duration/30/manifest_duration/30/vprv/1/playlist_type/DVR/initcwndbps/6610/mh/Ms/mm/44/mn/sn-25ge7nsl/ms/lva/mv/m/mvi/4/pl/30/keepalive/yes/mt/1603901358/disable_polymer/true/sparams/expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,ratebypass,live,goi,sgoap,sgovp,playlist_duration,manifest_duration,vprv,playlist_type/sig/AOq0QJ8wRAIgUQGg9L0Aj_FXl9CqYP0o8t-Dn23Jh0y93xgYGouOHZMCIExicbcOpmWTdWCrUExX8dHFMcPEDXtkXXRplyCl49Y1/lsparams/hls_chunk_host,initcwndbps,mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl/lsig/AG3C_xAwRQIhAKVCR3lS5k-ryagc8fHuvIzMuMDccwvOXmxj8fT7PjUyAiB8D1MwZ0tmEoJidXuttZSKuxCDlc-J5gV43lRScjepXQ%3D%3D/playlist/index.m3u8/sq/3831776/goap/clen%3D81030%3Blmt%3D1603879520260144/govp/clen%3D259194%3Blmt%3D1603879520260142/dur/5.000/file/seg.ts', retrying with new connection: Invalid argument
[https @ 0xf82e80] Cannot reuse HTTP connection for different host: r2---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com:-1 != r4---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com:-1
[hls,applehttp @ 0xc06250] keepalive request failed for 'https://r4---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/id/DWcJFNfaw9c.2/itag/96/source/yt_live_broadcast/expire/1603923091/ei/M5iZX4_VIMLUW57fiOAO/ip/2a01:cb00:39c:2900:835b:2f40:d2bf:7a5d/requiressl/yes/ratebypass/yes/live/1/goi/160/sgoap/gir%3Dyes%3Bitag%3D140/sgovp/gir%3Dyes%3Bitag%3D137/hls_chunk_host/r4---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com/playlist_duration/30/manifest_duration/30/vprv/1/playlist_type/DVR/initcwndbps/6610/mh/Ms/mm/44/mn/sn-25ge7nsl/ms/lva/mv/m/mvi/4/pl/30/keepalive/yes/mt/1603901358/disable_polymer/true/sparams/expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,ratebypass,live,goi,sgoap,sgovp,playlist_duration,manifest_duration,vprv,playlist_type/sig/AOq0QJ8wRAIgUQGg9L0Aj_FXl9CqYP0o8t-Dn23Jh0y93xgYGouOHZMCIExicbcOpmWTdWCrUExX8dHFMcPEDXtkXXRplyCl49Y1/lsparams/hls_chunk_host,initcwndbps,mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl/lsig/AG3C_xAwRQIhAKVCR3lS5k-ryagc8fHuvIzMuMDccwvOXmxj8fT7PjUyAiB8D1MwZ0tmEoJidXuttZSKuxCDlc-J5gV43lRScjepXQ%3D%3D/playlist/index.m3u8/sq/3831777/goap/clen%3D81157%3Blmt%3D1603879520260154/govp/clen%3D236880%3Blmt%3D1603879520260152/dur/5.000/file/seg.ts', retrying with new connection: Invalid argument
[https @ 0x112a390] Cannot reuse HTTP connection for different host: r2---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com:-1 != r4---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com:-1
[hls,applehttp @ 0xc06250] keepalive request failed for 'https://r4---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/id/DWcJFNfaw9c.2/itag/96/source/yt_live_broadcast/expire/1603923091/ei/M5iZX4_VIMLUW57fiOAO/ip/2a01:cb00:39c:2900:835b:2f40:d2bf:7a5d/requiressl/yes/ratebypass/yes/live/1/goi/160/sgoap/gir%3Dyes%3Bitag%3D140/sgovp/gir%3Dyes%3Bitag%3D137/hls_chunk_host/r4---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com/playlist_duration/30/manifest_duration/30/vprv/1/playlist_type/DVR/initcwndbps/6610/mh/Ms/mm/44/mn/sn-25ge7nsl/ms/lva/mv/m/mvi/4/pl/30/keepalive/yes/mt/1603901358/disable_polymer/true/sparams/expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,ratebypass,live,goi,sgoap,sgovp,playlist_duration,manifest_duration,vprv,playlist_type/sig/AOq0QJ8wRAIgUQGg9L0Aj_FXl9CqYP0o8t-Dn23Jh0y93xgYGouOHZMCIExicbcOpmWTdWCrUExX8dHFMcPEDXtkXXRplyCl49Y1/lsparams/hls_chunk_host,initcwndbps,mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl/lsig/AG3C_xAwRQIhAKVCR3lS5k-ryagc8fHuvIzMuMDccwvOXmxj8fT7PjUyAiB8D1MwZ0tmEoJidXuttZSKuxCDlc-J5gV43lRScjepXQ%3D%3D/playlist/index.m3u8/sq/3831778/goap/clen%3D81571%3Blmt%3D1603879520260164/govp/clen%3D239140%3Blmt%3D1603879520260162/dur/5.000/file/seg.ts', retrying with new connection: Invalid argument
^Cwebsocket connection is closing.
```

Is this something I should be concerned of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your internet connection, it looks like you have a low connections.